# redirect stdout and stderr to different file under sandboxing in linux

Tags: linux, shell, io, sandbox, rhel

I have an `Test.cpp` which is run under `sandbox`(RHEL7):

Test.cpp content:

```
#include<stdio>
 int main(void) {
  int a = 1/0;
  return 0;
 }
```

compile it using gcc(4.8) Test.cpp which produces the `a.out`
Now running a.out prints `floating pointing exception` on console

Now i thought that if i redirect stderr to a file, i expect the error to be printed in file.
But that is not the case it still continue to print in console.
Googling reveal that under such exception the program is terminated immediately and if you capture the stderr of bash then it should redirect.
So i run

```
su -c ./a.out 2>err
```

Bingo error get printed in err file.

Now the MAIN GAME STARTS
i want to run it under sandbox 
so i run:

```
su -c 'sandbox ./a.out 1>out 2>err'
```

But there is nothing printed in err file or in console.

**How to capture stdout and stderr under such situation ?**

Comment: **sandbox doesnt allow you the write to files** then how are you writing to files using `cat`?

Comment: i have added much more details in question

Comment: Try this command: `su -c 'sandbox ./a.out' 1>out 2>err`

Comment: "su -c 'sandbox ./a.out' 1>out 2>err" doesn't print....... but "su -c './a.out' 1>out 2>err" does print it in err file

Answer (score 1):

To be clear (you mention it in passing):  The error you want is printed by `bash`.  It's not printed as the dying gasp of your program.  So what matters is where the shell itself is redirected.

When you did:

```
su -c ./a.out 2>err
```

The redirection is part of the shell you executed in.  The `2>err` opens `err` as `stderr` for `su`.  `su` creates a shell which inherits `stderr` and eventually prints the error.

In this version:

```
su -c 'sandbox ./a.out 1>out 2>err'
```

You've quoted the redirection `'... 2>err'` so the `stderr` of the `su` is not affected.  The `sandbox` command is redirected.  However, the `sandbox` command may or may not use a shell to run the command, or it may use `exec cmd...`.  Either way, there is no shell waiting for your crash to print the message.

You could try:

```
su -c 'sandbox bash -c ./a.out 1>out 2>err'
```

That should ensure that there's a `bash` with the desired `stderr` around to print your result.

You can also catch this result yourself (and avoid having the shell print anything) with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

./a.out &
wait $!
echo $?
```

Invoking it in the background will prevent the usual output.  Then waiting for it (with explicit PID) will return an error code in `$?`.  If a process exits with a signal, the error code will be `128 + signum` (get the list from `kill -l`)

Answer (score 0):

```
sandbox ./a.out > pr 2> err
```

In your example you're redirecting stdout to the pipe, and cat's stderr to err.

Comment: hi i have edited question to be much more descriptive